# ASP.NET MVC Entity framework how to structure this code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a few structures: User, Item, FavouriteItem.

User has many items, and can have many faourite items (which just link to items).

I've got the decision of either creating a model: "FavouriteItem" and give a user a list of these, or, store the favourite item ids in a column on the user table. i.e favourite_items: "1,2,5,9".

The latter seems like it will be a lot faster if the user base grows, but then I have the pain of having to split the string, create an array e.t.c, it's a bit more painful.

What is the recommended choice to make here? I've already done the earlier option and love its flexibility/ease-of-use, but a bit worried about its scalability.

Answer (score 3):

How about User, Item, UserItem (link table which has a IsFavouriteItem bit field. So UserId, ItemId, IsFavouriteItem as the columns)?

Answer (score 1):

The best choice depends to some extend on the query patterns you will experience in your application.  I'm going to assume that Items are specific to a User and not shared between users.  Based on what you are saying, I would go with a structure something like:

```
public class User
{
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> FavoriteItems
    {
        get
        {
            return from i in Items where i.IsFavorite select i;
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

That will work well if the list of items per user is not huge, even if you have many users and many items.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of speed, it might be more effecient to store the `FavouriteItems` in the `User` table if you expect your table to be storing huge amounts of data. However, if you want a clean, structured database then I would introduce a foreign key table `UserItems` with a `Favourite` column e.g.

```
UserItems
---------        
UserId           
ItemId
Favourite
```

You can always optimize your query if you start to hit bottlenecks.